# how to create a function which has a function as one of its arguments react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a function which takes in a function (in this case a react hook useState function) as one of its arguments in order to simplify the below code (I have shown just 2 columns my actual data has about 30 columns hence why I'm trying to simplify)

```
const [teamName, setTeamName] = useState('')
const [teamLocation, setTeamLocation] = useState('')

    <div classname="editHere">
    <input value={teamName} onChange={(e) => {  setTeamName(e.target.value) }}/>
    </div>

    <div className="editHere">
    <input value={teamLocation} onChange={(e) => {  setTeamLocation(e.target.value) }}/>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to do this with the following function

```
function dropDownRow(value, setValue()) {
        return (
            <div className="editHere">
            <input value={value} onChange={(e) => {  setValue(e.target.value) }}/>
            </div>
        )

    }
```

and then to return what is shown in the first snippet I wanted to type

```
{dropDownRow(teamName, setTeamName())}
{dropDownRow(teamLocation, setTeamLocation())}
```

Obviously this does not work so does anyone have any suggestions on how I could do what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your function like this ...

```
function DropDownRow({ value, setValue }) {
  return (
    <div className="editHere">
      <input value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

and your references should like like ...

```
      <DropDownRow value={teamName} setValue={setTeamName} />
      <DropDownRow value={teamLocation} setValue={setTeamLocation} />
```

[Example Here ...](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-brahmagupta-dzk5e?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Remove parenthesis here :

```
function dropDownRow(value, setValue) {
```

And here :

```
{dropDownRow(teamName, setTeamName)}
{dropDownRow(teamLocation, setTeamLocation)}
```

or you can also use a cleaner syntax :

```
const DropDownRow = ({ value, setValue }) => ...
```

then

```
<DropDownRow value={teamName} setValue={setTeamName} />
<DropDownRow value={teamLocation} setValue={setTeamLocation} />
```